# How to warmup an asp.net core app hosted in IIS (a) on website restart and (b) on redeploy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I am hosting an asp.net core 2.0 app in IIS. The app is only started when at least one web request was sent to the website. However, I need the app to start when the app is (a) restarted in IIS and (b) on redployment (publish to folder). By "start" I mean that the `Startup` Class is constructed and its ConfigureServices(...) and Configure(...) methods are called, because I have configured a few singleton services that need to be instantiated as soon as the web host is started and not just as soon as the first web request comes in.

Here is the entry point of my app:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 10485760, retainedFileCountLimit: 10) // 10485760 Bytes = 10Megabytes
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: After a publish/IIS reset, either manually submit an HTTP request or automatically submit one with a service.

Comment: Here's a [free 3rd-party service](https://uptimerobot.com/) you can use to hit a URL every 5 minutes, essentially keeping your application "warm".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Unfortunately, sending a manual request is not an option (must be automized and singletons must be instantiated immediately on webservice restart and redeploy), and sending a request every X timeframe leads to the risk of X time long no services being initialized.

Comment: In my opinion. I suggest you could try to use IIS Initialization to achieve your requirement , autowarm up the application after it started. You could add below config in the web.config after installed the  IIS Initialization from control panel.`<applicationInitialization
    remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm" 
    skipManagedModules="true" >
  <add initializationPage="/default.aspx" />
</applicationInitialization>` Details [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options to automatically send HTTP requests to your web application.

- [Uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com/) is one of many free third-party services that will periodically send requests to your web application.
- Create and host your own Windows service (assuming you lean towards Microsoft solutions) that hits your web service at any frequency you wish.
- Create an Azure Function (or AWS Lambda) with a [timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp) to hit your web service at any frequency you wish.
- Setup a release with tools like [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/) that includes a post-release task that sends a request to your web application.
- Install and configure the [IIS Application Initialization Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) to perform warmup tasks.

Comment: Thank your for all the options! They inspired me to come up with the following solution to my specific problem: I created a Windows Scheduled Task that sends via Powershell an HTTP GET request to a "keepWarm" endpoint every minute.

Comment: Oh - That's a pretty good solution, too. I didn't know you could set up a scheduled task to trigger powershell scripts. Glad you found something that works.