# .Net core web api configure services before Startup is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm creating .net core 3.1 web api application. By default, it is configured to use `IHostBuilder` with `Startup` file which does some configurations

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

I want to add some configurations into my `Startup` file (events producing) and the problem is that they will not be executed on the application startup but only when api receives the first request.
That means that my hosted application won't be able to handle events before it gets a request.
So the question is: How can I invoke configuration methods from the `Startup` file on the application start or how can I do specific configuration that will be executed on the application start?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The whole point of a web application is to process HTTP requests. If it's processing other things, it should not be a webapp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your `Program.Main` entry point.

Modify this autogenerated code:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

To:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    // Use DI via host.Services:
    var myConfiguredService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<SomeService>();
    myConfiguredService.DoSomething();

    host.Run();
}
```

That was the [preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46688953/460298) to initialized DB with data in EF 2.0, and still works great for other purposes.

This (`Main`) method runs when `dotnet run` is executed, before it receives any requests.

**But if you host webapp behind IIS** be aware that IIS will not actually launch your app until it receives first request! So, you can't solve this problem "inside" your app, and I don't know if new/latest IIS has any settings about this.

Instead, you may use any uptime monitoring service and set it to check your webapp every 1-3-5 minutes, so your webapp will receive some "fake" request and spin up before actual "business" request arrives.

P.S. If you need async/await - change `void Main` to `async Task Main` and `host.Run()` to `await host.RunAsync()` (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that the Main method does not get invoked either. Only when the first request comes...

Comment: Main method will be invoked when your app will launch/start (when `dotnet run` will be executed). If you host webapp, say, behind IIS and IIS does not start your app until first request received - this can't be solved "inside" your app.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem! I've debugged it from VS with default run command. Thank you!. Include this into the answer and I'll accept it as a correct answer

Comment: You have multiple options to warm up iis to prepare the app beforehand:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184181/3224794